# Name duplicates previous WSGI daemon definition

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm changing the domain name of a site.  For a period I want the old domain name and the new domain name to point to the site.  I'm running a Python Django site.

My original Apache2 conf works fine and the basis is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin name@gmail.com
        ServerName originalsite.co.uk
        ServerAlias www.originalsite.co.uk
        DocumentRoot /var/www/originalsite
        WSGIDaemonProcess originalsite python-path=/var/www/originalsite:/var/www/originalsite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup originalsite
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/originalsite/originalsite/wsgi.py
        ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I set up a new conf file with only the following changes:

```
    ServerName newsite.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.newsite.co.uk
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> Name duplicates previous WSGI daemon definition.

How do I fix this?  Thanks for your help

Comment: how about changin `originalsite` name ? not in the directory address just the name like `WSGIDaemonProcess somethingelse python-path=/var/www/originalsite:/var/www/originalsite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
and `WSGIProcessGroup somethingelse `

Comment: So easy! Thank you

Comment: Hi, is it possible to delete a specific WSGI process and group?
because I need to reuse the same name.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

change `originalsite` name

not in the directory address just the name like

```
WSGIDaemonProcess somethingelse python-path=/var/www/originalsite:/var/www/originalsite/env/‌​lib/python2.7/site-p‌​ackages
```

and

```
WSGIProcessGroup somethingelse
```

Comment: @jinchuika i've never used it on https so no , but you can always check apache error log to see why it wont work .. open 2 ssh clients in 1 do something like `tail -f /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log` so it shows apache erro log in real time and in other one try to start apache you'll see what causing the error

Comment: Could you @max please check my detailed question about this topic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983577/wsgi-error-with-two-ssl-virtual-hosts-and-apache

Answer (score 23):

If you're facing this issue while using `certbot` command to install multiple "Let's Encrypt Certificates" then it may be due to some bug in `certbot`, as discussed [here](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/4880). For a quick workaround, you can comment

```
WSGIScriptAlias 
WSGIDaemonProcess 
WSGIProcessGroup
```

to run `certbot` command and then remove the comments afterwards.

Comment: Then you get a new config file ending with "-le-ssl.conf" that require a uniqure name for the WSGIDaemonProcess and WSGIProcessGroup.

Answer (score 7):

The reason for the error is because the name of a mod_wsgi daemon process group must be unique across the whole Apache installation. It is not possible to use the same daemon process group name in different `VirtualHost` definitions. This is necessary to avoid conflicts when working out what daemon process group is being referred to in certain situations.

Comment: // , How can we make them different? If they're different, what impact does it typically have on application behavior?

Comment: You make them different by using a different name for each. There is no impact because if they are different WSGI applications best practice is to run them in separate daemon process groups. If the problem is that you are trying to create separate daemon process groups for HTTP vs HTTPS virtual host, don't do that. Drop ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` from the second and have ``WSGIProcessGroup`` use name on process group from the first ``VirtualHost``. This is special case for HTTP/HTTPS ``VirtualHost`` pairs.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved this problem by commenting the below 3 lines in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

```
# WSGIDaemonProcess 
# WSGIProcessGroup 
# WSGIScriptAlias
```

then reload/restart Apache2.

And I leave them as is in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf` because it's duplicated in HTTP (non-SSL) and HTTPS (SSL)

Comment: For certbot, I had `WSGIDaemonProcess atemoncom` in non ssl conf. When certbot copied same, the new server on ssl has the same  `WSGIDaemonProcess atemoncom`  and  threw error. To fix that, I commented the line as above, then added certbot, then un-commented it in ssl and non-ssl conf. then I changed it to `WSGIDaemonProcess atemoncom`  for non ssl conf and `WSGIDaemonProcess sslatemoncom` for ssl conf.

Now both ssl and non-ssl has different names and hence no error

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with Apache2 configuration.
In my case I have duplicated 000-default.conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled.

First I looking 'WSGIDaemon' string in Linux:

```
grep -iRl "WSGIDaemon" ./
```

Second analize every line. I found duplicated file on `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-copy.conf`. After delete, checking syntax:

```
sudo apachectl configtest
```

return 'Syntax OK'. I spend on this 4 hours... I hope somebody use this :)

Answer (score 1):

Although there are correct answers given, I was still confused when reading the answers. So here's some clarification for the particular case when enabling HTTP and HTTPS for a single site on Apache.

In one of your configuration files (let's say HTTP):

```
# Add this outside of VirtualHost scope to ensure it's global
WSGIDaemonProcess some_name python-path=/var/www/originalsite:/var/www/originalsite/env/‌​lib/python2.7/site-p‌​ackages

...


# Within VirtualHost
WSGIProcessGroup some_name
```

In the other configuration file (HTTPS):

```
WSGIProcessGroup some_name
```

That's it. What it does is link the same group in both the config files. The process name is defined only in one config files and that makes Apache happy.

Comment: i had this same issue but after following your procedure, i was able to set up the ssl certificate successfully.Thanks